# Optimize query with multiple OR conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which I'm trying to search with a single word that could be the person's name, his/her mother's name, or either one of his/her IDs numbers.

Here is my query:

```
select pf.id,
(i.FirstName + ' ' + i.SecondName +' ' + i.ThirdName + ' '+i.FourthName) as Name
,(i.MotherFirstName + ' ' + i.MotherSecondName +' ' + i.MotherThirdName) as MotherName
,(select Alias From FormStatuses where id = (select top(1) StatusId from BeneficiaryStatus where BeneficiaryId = pf.Id order by CreatedDate desc)) ALias
,(select NameEn From FormStatuses where id = (select top(1) StatusId from BeneficiaryStatus where BeneficiaryId = pf.Id order by CreatedDate desc)) Status
,(Case When exists (select 1 from CaseManagementForms where PeopleId = pf.Id) then  1 Else 0 End) HasCase

from PeopleForms  pf inner join FormPersonalInfos i on pf.Id = i.PeopleFormId
Left outer join CivilStatusIds c on pf.CivilStatusId = c.Id
left outer join NationalCards n on pf.NationalCardId = n.Id 
left outer join PdsCards p on pf.PdsCardId = p.Id 

where i.FullName like 'Azad100087%' or i.MotherFullName like 'Azad100087%'

or c.Number = 'Azad100087' 
or n.Number = 'Azad100087' 
or p.Number = 'Azad100087'
or pf.Code = 'Azad100087'
or pf.OldCode = 'Azad100087'
```

I have tried so many different ways, multi joins, sub-queries in the where, or cross/outer apply... etc but with no luck.

I have proper indexes on each of those fields that I want to search for.

The number for records of each table is 400,000+ records and the time I get is 2 seconds.

If I decrease the number of ORs (e.g. only remain the name and mother name) then its completely fine (117ms).

Here is my execution plan link : [Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyw3fWRoP)

Any tips are highly appreciated.

**Update:**

Here is my execution plan link using OR, the time went from 2 seconds to 700+ms:

[Execution Plan using UNION](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyw3fWRoP)

**Update 2:**

I make a small change to the database schema and used `UNION ALL`, the time now is between 60-90 ms

[EP using UNION ALL](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry7NUf0jP)

Comment: Often `UNION ALL` solves `OR` performance issues.

Comment: @DaleK Please see my updated answer, i tried using OR, am i doing it the correct way?

Comment: @DaleK sorry,i tried using union all and union and both gave similar results

Comment: Neither of those plans has a `UNION ALL` (which is very different from `UNION`). What is the time of execution using `UNION ALL`? And maybe show your `UNION ALL` so we can see if you are doing it correctly.

Comment: @DaleK ok now i updated my answer with the UNION all, is there any more room for performance improvements or its the far best i can do

Comment: 60-90ms seems a pretty good improvement over 2s?

Comment: `UNION` is often slower... always `UNION ALL`. `UNION` also de-duplicates the data which can be slow.

Comment: well definitely UNION all had better performance (but honestly not that significant different in my case ). i wanted if there more room for my query to be tuned, as the records now is 400,000, but we should also consider 1,000,000+

Comment: That kind of generic query can often be hard to optimise. Personally I would be OK with 60ms... you say not that significant, 2s down to 60ms is a 95% improvement? You might want to try https://dba.stackexchange.com/ if you are serious about getting it faster.

Comment: i would do,thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dale-k's answer in the comment just solved my performance problem.

The solution to multiple `OR` bad performances is to use `UNION ALL`. my execution time dropped to 60-90ms from 700+ms.